# Replace null character in a string in sql

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to replace a null character in a sql string, i cant seem to find the right command to achieve this. I have used replace (myString ,'\0', '') but this seems not to work, any help would be great

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use this:

```
REPLACE(myString, char(0), '')
```

Comment: switching to use REPLACE(myString, char(0), '') still generates returns a null character in a string

Comment: Please show how myString is being generated and/or sample data.

Comment: I am sorry i cannot eleborate more, The replace string function works. the way described thank you for the help.

Comment: DOES NOT WORK FOR UNICODE!  Sorry, had to shout that out.  This is apparently a Bug in the SQL Server Replace() function that it does not replace null-characters in nVarChar's.  And yes, I tried nChar(0), and it still doesn't work.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2828467/555798

Comment: For Unicode support, see the answers that use COLLATE.

Comment: For Sybase this worked by using `str_replace` with the same parameters.

Answer (score 19):

The trick that works is to COLLATE your value to **Latin1_General_BIN** before using REPLACE and also use  **nchar(0x00)      COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN** for **string_pattern**.

REPLACE ( string_expression , **string_pattern** , string_replacement )

```
 select 
 [Terminated]      =          N'123' + nchar(0) + N'567'                                
,[Replaced with -] = REPLACE((N'123' + nchar(0) + N'567') COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
                                          , nchar(0x00) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN 
                                                 ,'-')      
,[Removed]        = REPLACE((N'123' + nchar(0) + N'567') COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
                                    , nchar(0x00)      COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
                                            ,'')
```

Here is the result (use Output To Text):

```
Contains   Replaced with -   Removed
---------- ----------------- --------
123 567    123-567           123567
```

Answer (score 7):

These functions remove null characters from Unicode strings, at least in SQL Server 2008.

```
-- Remove all null characters
CREATE FUNCTION RemoveNulls(@s nvarchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @r nvarchar(max);
    SET @r = REPLACE(@s COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, NCHAR(0), N'');
    RETURN @r; 
END
```

```
-- Remove all characters from the first null character
CREATE FUNCTION TrimNull(@s nvarchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @r nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @i int = CHARINDEX(NCHAR(0), @s COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN);
    IF @i = 0
        SET @r = @s;
    ELSE
        SET @r = SUBSTRING(@s, 1, @i - 1);
    RETURN @r; 
END
```

```
-- Example usage
DECLARE @s nvarchar(10) = N'Test' + NCHAR(0) + N'!';
SELECT dbo.RemoveNulls(@s), dbo.TrimNull(@s);
--> Test!, Test
```

In my case, fields from ODBC were padded to 8000 characters with null and TrimNull was much faster than RemoveNulls.

Comment: I wish I could give this 10 up votes.  This is the only post I found that uses COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN instead of SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.  The latter does NOT work for me but your collation does!  Not an easy thing to figure out on my own.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For latin characters:
select REPLACE('Ho'+CHAR(0)+'mer' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, CHAR(0), '')

For russian characters:
select REPLACE(('Го'+CHAR(0)+'мер') COLLATE Cyrillic_General_BIN , CHAR(0), '')

Answer (score 4):

If you *Only* have **ASCII** (Char/VarChar) strings then this will work as @DyingCactus suggests:

```
REPLACE(myString, Char(0x00), '')
```

**However**, if you are dealing with [Null-Terminated Strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) and are trying to fix or convert to something like XML, and your data is **Unicode** (nChar/nVarChar), then use this:

```
(CASE WHEN UNICODE(SUBSTRING(myString, LEN(myString), 1)) = 0x0000
      THEN SUBSTRING(myString, 1, LEN(myString) - 1)
      ELSE myString END)
```

This works for both ASCII (Char/VarChar) and Unicode (nChar/nVarChar).

### Note

Using the Replace() function with Char(0) or nChar(0) will ***NOT*** work for Unicode (nChar/nVarChar).
It's a **bug** in the SQL Server Replace() function.

You could cast as VarChar, then use Replace(), but then you would lose any special Unicode/Non-ASCII characters you might have intended to keep.
Otherwise you wouldn't have used the Unicode datatype (that takes up twice as much space to store your data) in the first place.


If you have Null-Characters mixed in with your Unicode strings (and not only at the end), and, for the purposes of your query, maintaining Unicode-specific characters are unimportant, then as a last resort you could use this :

```
(CASE WHEN myString LIKE (N'%' + nCHAR(0x0000) + N'%')--Has Null-Character(s).
      THEN REPLACE(CAST(myString as VarChar(MAX)), Char(0x00), '')--Cast as ASCII
      ELSE myString END)--Else, leave as Unicode to preserve Unicode-Only chars.
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure what is wrong with your strings, but here are some things to try, are you using varchar?, edit question with more details:

if you have NULL characters within a string:

```
declare @x varchar(10)
set @x='123'+char(0)+'456'
SELECT @x AS Has_NULL_in_it, REPLACE(@x, char(0), '') AS Has_NULL_removed
```

OUTPUT:

```
Has_NULL_in_it Has_NULL_removed
-------------- ----------------
123 456        123456

(1 row(s) affected)
```

If you can't tell the character within the string, try this ASCII:

```
DECLARE @y varchar(10),@c int
set @y='123'+char(0)+'456'
set @c=0
WHILE @c<LEN(@y)
BEGIN
    SET @c=@c+1
    PRINT CONVERT(varchar(5),@c)+' - '+SUBSTRING(@y,@c,1)+' - CHAR('+CONVERT(varchar(5),ASCII(SUBSTRING(@y,@c,1)))+')'
END
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 - 1 - CHAR(49)
2 - 2 - CHAR(50)
3 - 3 - CHAR(51)
4 - - CHAR(0)
5 - 4 - CHAR(52)
6 - 5 - CHAR(53)
7 - 6 - CHAR(54)
```

try this unicode:

```
DECLARE @y nvarchar(10),@c int
set @y='123'+char(0)+'456'
set @c=0
WHILE @c<LEN(@y)
BEGIN
    SET @c=@c+1
    PRINT CONVERT(nvarchar(5),@c)+' - '+SUBSTRING(@y,@c,1)+' - UNICODE('+CONVERT(nvarchar(5),UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@y,@c,1)))+')'
END
```

if your have strings that are completely NULL:

```
declare @z varchar(10)
set @z=NULL
select @z AS IS_NULL, ISNULL(@Z,'') AS NULL_Removed
```

OUTPUT:

```
IS_NULL    NULL_Removed
---------- ------------
NULL       

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: The first part of this ansawer depends on choice of collation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concatenating values to get your string use [IsNull(value, replacement)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) to avoid having null values or set [CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862%28SQL.80%29.aspx) ON to avoid null strings as a result.

Comment: **NEVER EVER EVER use CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL**, it is not going to be supported beyond SQL Server 2008, make sure it is set ON by default and handle all string concatenations with regard to NULL: COALESCE, ISNULL, and/or NULLIF

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem: Ending \0 character in nvarchar fields and unable to replace it with any of the REPLACE variants proposed (SQL Server 2008). When using

```
LEFT(Bar, LEN(Bar)-1)
```

it cut off the last regular character together with the \0 !

Our solution now to correct the fields is (as weird as it may seem on a first glimpse):

```
UPDATE Foo
    SET Bar = LEFT(Bar, LEN(Bar))
WHERE RIGHT(Bar, 1) = CHAR(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Examples resolved

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.F_ReplaceNullChar( @STR NVARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @i INT=0
DECLARE @RET NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
    WHILE @I<LEN(@STR) 
    BEGIN 
        SET @i=@i+1
        IF UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@STR,@i,1)) <> 0x0000
            SET @RET=@RET+SUBSTRING(@STR,@i,1)

    END
    RETURN @RET
END
GO

SELECT LEN(mycol) lenbefore,mycol,
 LEN( dbo.F_ReplaceNullChar(mycol)) lenafter, dbo.F_ReplaceNullChar(mycol) mycolafter 
FROM mytab
```

Answer (score -1):

select zz.xx
, replace(zz.xx, '�', '')
from (
select
t.string_with_null,
(
select s.string_with_null+''
from TABLE_1 s
where s.token_hash = t.token_hash
for xml path('')
) xx
from TABLE_1 t(nolock)
)zz