# Error converting text to varbinary with format 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, varbinarymax

I have a spreadsheet of data, which is basically PART_ID and SPECS. The SPECS field is a large character string which, when imported into a temporary table, is stored as NVARCHAR(255).

Example:

'Widget', 'This part needs to be heated to 400 degrees before cutting.'

The ultimate table this has to go into for our ERP system stores the SPECS as a binary field.

If I do the following, I get a binary conversion:

```
INSERT INTO ERP_PART_TABLE (PART_ID, SPEC)
SELECT PART_ID, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), SPEC) FROM TEMP_TABLE;
```

However, when I then go into the ERP system, all I see is the first character, and I get a chime telling me the system encountered some weird character.

I have seen this done in past conversions with a different conversion format, such as:

```
INSERT INTO ERP_PART_TABLE (PART_ID, SPEC)
SELECT PART_ID, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), SPEC, 1) FROM TEMP_TABLE;
```

However, when I try to select with that formatted conversion, I get

> 'Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type
>   nvarchar to varbinary.'

I have tried a `TRY_CONVERT(varbinary(max), bits, 1)` and the results came back consistently NULL.

Is there potentially some special character in my original text field that I'm not seeing?  (Just for a test, I also tried `selecting CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 'Hello',1)` and I still get the error.)

SQL*Server 2012.

Comment: Check if your data has `\0` null character. `select Replaced = replace('BAD_STRING_OR_COLUMN_NAME' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, nchar(0x00) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN ,'') ` then try casting to varbinary.

Comment: And read [Null Literal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2828467/5070879)

Comment: I have found a solution. It lies in converting the bits to VARCHAR within the converstion to VARBINARY. Like so:  SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(max), CONVERT(varchar(max), spec)).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may help if you have problem with Null Literal or `\0`. Code below will remove them.

```
SELECT
    PART_ID,
    CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), REPLACE(SPEC COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, NCHAR(0x00) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN ,'') , 1) 
FROM TEMP_TABLE;
```