# Strange Nul issue in SQL Server script data

Tags: sql-server

I have created a sql server script of a large database table (more than 2 GB). while running the script I got this error: "**Unclosed quotation mark after the character string.**" While trying to debug the issue I have found that there is a strange "**NUL**" value between text. This "**NUL**" is only visible in Notepad++.

Anyone knows how to make script of database table without this "**NUL**". {If I remove this manually script works fine. But I am not able to remove it manually as some tables are more than 10 GB}

[image]

Thanks

Comment: How did you generate this script?

Comment: Using SQL Server. Tasks=>Generate Scripts

Comment: I guess your data contains `NUL` literal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828333/what-is-the-null-character-literal-in-tsql. Check for one column with it `SELECT col_name, LEN(col_name) , DATA_LENGTH(col_name) FROM table WHERE id = ?`

Comment: Any Idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: Probably you will need to clean your data. Or use replace in Notepad++ `NUL` to empty

Comment: be careful that your script does not include or introduce unexpected characters. look through your script for unexpected whitespace at the end of lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all I have solved my issue.

I was reading data from NON MS Sql Database and inserting into MS SQL server using asp .net ADO way. During testing of the cause I found that there is invalid data "NUL" in the existing database. So I modified my insertion code and just replaced "NUL" with "Blank" using REGEX.

```
Regex.Replace(MyDataColumnName, "\x00", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Now there is no "NUL".