# Query with null-terminated strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a T-SQL script to align two copies of a database with the 
[**`tablediff`** utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/tablediff-utility) exposed by SQL Server but I am facing a problem with all the rows of a text field inside a table.

The problem is that all the strings stored on that text field are null-terminated (there actually is a null character at the end of the string if I export them to a text file) and the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries generated by `tablediff` are all failing due to the fact that that null terminator truncates the query.

Is there a way to prevent the generated scripts from failing?

**UPDATE**

Creation query generated by MSSQL for the table I'm trying to align

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABTEST](
    [Code] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Source] [text] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PrK_TABTEST] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Code] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Insert query generated by `tablediff` (keep in mind that the character you don't see at the end of the `Source` after the `NOOP` is an ANSI NULL character)

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TABTEST] SET [Source]=N'NOOP ' WHERE [Code] = N'TestCode'
```

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828333/what-is-the-null-character-literal-in-tsql

Comment: You can try post-processing the scripts with a custom written util (e.g. a C# console app) and replace the failing `...\0'` with `...' + char(0)` - assuming that you want to preserve the 0-characters.

Comment: @PeterB the fact is that I'm am writing this script to align two databases so that I can create all the update scripts to generate updates for our application and we have to do all inside the SQL script

Comment: You could run the fixer app from inside your main script, search `sql server call exe` for more info.

Comment: Oh with `xp_shellcmd`...we could try that if there isn't another solution

Answer (score 0):

The `CHAR(0)` can be nasty...

My suggestion is to cut the last character away, `LEN()` will return the lengt including this `0x0`. Try it out:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100)='test' + CHAR(0)

SELECT @s + 'extension' AS Result1,
       LEFT(@s,LEN(@s)-1) + 'extension' AS Result2;
```