# In SQL Server, replace a Char(0), the null character, embedded in a string with its hex code

Tags: sql-server, replace, hex, nul

What is a construct in SQL Server T-SQL that will replace a `Char(0)`, the null character, embedded in a string with its hex code?

I.e.

```
 REPLACE('t'+Char(0)+'t', Char(0), REPLACE(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(0), '000000', ''))
```

does not return `'t0x00t'`, what does? (This does already work for 1 through 31.)

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298412/replace-null-character-in-a-string-in-sql) has answers explaining the problem is the Collation.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5172100/256431) shows `master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(0)` will return `0x00000000`.

When I manually simplified the inner `Replace` to `'0x00'`, just adding a `Collate` clause did get it to work, like the answers to the above question suggested, but I can't find a version that works for the full expression (which then could be used for all n, 0 to 31, skipping 9, 10 and 13).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want might be this.

```
SELECT REPLACE('t'+Char(0)+'t', Char(0), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),REPLACE(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(0), '000000', '')))
```

You need to convert it explicitly to VARCHAR

and if you want the full expression remove inner replace

```
SELECT REPLACE('t'+Char(0)+'t', Char(0), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(0)))
```

Comment: Just for completeness the final SQL:`with m as (select 0 as n union all select n+1 from m where n<31)
  update Messages
  set MessageText = replace(MessageText,
        char(n) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS,
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
        replace(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(5), '000000', '')))
  from m where n not in (9, 10, 12, 13)
    and MessageText like '%'
      + char(n) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
      + '%'

`