# SQL delete NULL containing strings

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains a list of titles.

And due to a problem something went wrong and the values now are like

```
title1[null]
title2[null][null]
title[null]3[null]
```

And the likes, I need to replace all [NULL] to NOTHING. so everything will be okay again. THank you.

Please advice.

PS.

[null] is not an actual string but the value NULL itself like the hex 00.

Comment: Your schema and values aren't understandable, plz elaborate more, or use SQL fiddle or some other tool to convey your problem.

Comment: SQL server ? Use REPLACE function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stackoverflow already has an existing answer:

```
REPLACE(myString, char(0), '')
```

Source: [Replace null character in a string in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298412/replace-null-character-in-a-string-in-sql)

This might help too: [What is the Null Character literal in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828333/what-is-the-null-character-literal-in-tsql)

Answer (score 1):

This is for MS SQL

```
 UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, '[null]', '')
```

**NEW ANSWER AFTER UPDATE ABOUT '[NULL]' BEING THE NULL CHARACTER, NOT TEXT:**

```
 UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, char(0), '')
```

Comment: @nambla What it the problem with it? Works for me.

Comment: @nambla Ah I get the issue now... I thought you meant the text '[null]' was in the string, not the actual null character! Answer updated!