Dynamic pivot column list always with trailing whitespace
I have a problem creating a dynamic pivot table in SQL Server 2012.
My main table consists of timestamp,node_id,value columns:



timestamp
node_id
value




1
1
1


2
2
2



I have another table t_node with nodename (NVARCHAR(400)) for each node_id.
I want to have a pivot table with



timestamp
nodename1
nodename2
nodename3




1
123
1
123


2
456
2
455



and so on.
I created a dynamic list first with all nodenames like HERE:
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)    

SELECT @cols = isnull(@cols + ',', '') + '[' + nodename + ']'
FROM [MyDB].[DBSpace01].t_node
ORDER BY nodename

When I print this @cols, I always get trailing whitespaces at the end of each entry - like this:
[nodename1 ], [nodename2 ], [nodename3 ]

This then leads to errors when pivoting with this list because it results in an error:

'nodename1.' is an invalid name because it contains a NULL character or an invalid Unicode character.

I tried RTRIM and REPLACE and everything, but the list is either empty or has the whitespaces in the end. I also tried to have it with QUOTENAMES, but then the list is empty.
I do not understand enough of SQL Server to understand what exactly is going wrong here.
Any help is appreciated.
As in the comments requested here are some results of
SELECT CAST(nodename AS  VARBINARY(MAX))  FROM [MyDB].[DBSpace01].t_node

0x41004900530049004E0054002F004D004D00530049004C006900730074002F0030000000
0x41004900530049004E0054002F004D004D00530049004C006900730074002F0031000000


Can you add some results from SELECT CAST(nodename AS  VARBINARY(MAX))  FROM [MyDB].[DBSpace01].t_node? Presumably they end with some character that is not a space. Maybe 0x00. The method of string concatenation you are using is not guaranteed to work BTW but won't cause this. You should be using STRING_AGG

Thanks for the hint. I added some results.

What version of SQL Server are you using?

Among other things trailing whitespace is still stored in varchar and nvarchar columns, e.g.: db<>fiddle, they're just not counted by LEN(). i.e.: have you tried trimming them?

SQL Server 11.0.6020

@AlwaysLearning yes, I tried Trimming when creating @cols and also in the FOR IN part of the pivot. Did not help.

So that doesn't support RTRIM with specific characters. You can just REPLACE NCHAR(0) with an empty space. As this is the problem trailing 0000

Like this? REPLACE(nodename,NCHAR(0),'') Did not help. Still the same.

You might need to add an explicit COLLATE clause if that doesn't get rid of it and it still ends with 0x0000 after the REPLACE. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24453456/73226

FYI, using the syntax SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM is a documented antipattern and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your data in a row by row order, which there is no guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using STRING_AGG, however, in older versions you'll need to use FOR XML PATH (and STUFF) to achieve the same results.

Yaay, Thanks @MartinSmith , COLLATE did the job. Thank you all very much, also for the hints about the antipattern issue.
